# CPU spikes to 100% site doesn't load, VPS crashes after moving site

Tags: installation

I moved my site to a virtual private server(VPS) because my sharing web hosting account doesn't support the growing number of visitors, but when i install it, CPU spikes to 100%, site doesn't load and vps crashes.
I tried everything; desactivating all plugins, deleting all plugins, checking database, installing a fresh copy of WordPress but still the same problem.
I asked my hosting and they said that the problem comes from my site.
i tested the website on two different shared web hosting account and it worked fine.
so the website works on a shared webhosting and doesn't work on a vps or dedicated server.
I have been trying to find a solution for 3 weeks and i'm getting crazy ,Please someone helppppppppppppppp.

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to disable access to your site for all but you in .htaccess file:

```
deny from all
allow from 11.11.11.11
```

where 11.11.11.11 is your current IP. If your site is crashing the VPS even then, this means that you have an epic misconfiguration of the VPS. Having a closer look at the resource-greedy processes using the console command **top** (or installing **htop**, which is better) would give you some more hints on the case.

If your site works well just for you after you've limited access to others, it's time to see what's wrong with it - profiling, fine-tuning of your web-server (apache or other), your MySQL, caching and so on.

I had a funny case of an anti-virus and anti-spam daemons slowing page-load with more than 10 seconds without having any load on the site... so stay open minded for stuff like this!